# How to convert this thing [(a, ),(b, ),(c, ),(d, )] into [a,b,c,d]?

Tags: python

I am trying to fetch data from SQL(integer) and put it in a empty list then add the data fetched from SQL and print it , but i am continuously facing the above mentioned problem.

I always get error , i tried to convert the nested list in flat lost but couldn't able , i always get error saying:

Type Error: can only concatenate list(not "tuple") to list.

Comment: `[e[0] for e in [(a, ),(b, ),(c, ),(d, )]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to extract values from the tuples and put them in a list:

```
my_list = [(a, ),(b, ),(c, ),(d, )]
new_list = [x[0] for x in my_list]
print(new_list) # [a, b, c, d]
```